# Corona handling very specific touch events

Tags: android, menu, touch, coronasdk

I have an app with a left sliding menu, like the ones in any typical google application. I have a touch handler to close the menu when the user swipes left but the menu also uses a table to show elements of the menu, and this table has an `onRowTouch` handle to handle when a row button is clicked.

My problem now is, when the user wants to swipe the menu left to close it, if the users finger makes contact with any of the buttons, it throws the `onRowTouch` instead of closing the menu. And if the user tries to close the menu by swiping left over a button, it again throws the `onRowTouch` instead of closing the menu.

Is there a way to let the app know the difference between a touch intended to close the menu and one intended to just be click?

My code:

```
local sideMargin= 16
local function panelTransDone( target )
    --native.showAlert( "Panel", "Complete", { "Okay" } )
    if ( target.completeState ) then
        print( "PANEL STATE IS: "..target.completeState )
    end
end

--Panel being the menu
panel = widget.newPanel{
    location = "left",
    onComplete = panelTransDone,
    width = display.contentWidth * 0.8,
    height = display.contentHeight,
    speed = 150,
}
panel.background = display.newRect( 0, 0, panel.width, panel.height )
panel.background:setFillColor( 1 )
panel:insert( panel.background )

--Decorator elements omitted for readability

local menuRows= {
    {title = "Calendar", page = "calendar", image = "images/event/Icon.png"},
    {title = "Volunteer", page = "volunteer", image = "images/volunteer/Icon.png"},
    {title = "Contact Us", page = "contact", image = "images/chat/Icon.png"},
    {title = "About Us", page = "about", image = "images/info/Icon.png"},
    {title = "Sign Out", page = "signOut", image = "images/account/Icon.png"}
}
local function onRowRender( event )

    -- Get reference to the row group
    local row = event.row
    local params=event.row.params

    -- Cache the row "contentWidth" and "contentHeight" because the row bounds can change as children objects are added
    local rowHeight = row.contentHeight
    local rowWidth = row.contentWidth

    local textMargin= 72

    row.Image = display.newImageRect(row, params.image, 25, 25)
    row.Image.anchorX = 0
    row.Image.x = sideMargin
    row.Image.y = rowHeight/2

    row.rowTitle = display.newText( row, params.title, 0, 0, nil, 14, "left" )
    row.rowTitle:setFillColor( 0 )
    row.rowTitle.anchorX = 0
    row.rowTitle.x = textMargin
    row.rowTitle.y = rowHeight/2

    row:insert( row.Image )
    row:insert( row.rowTitle )
end

local function onRowTouch( event )
    local row = event.target
    local params=event.target.params

--when a row is clicked, it goes to the appropriate page
    panel:hide()
    composer.removeScene(composer.getSceneName("current"))
    composer.gotoScene( params.page)

end


local scrollBarOptions = {
    sheet = scrollBarSheet,  -- Reference to the image sheet
    topFrame = 1,            -- Number of the "top" frame
    middleFrame = 2,         -- Number of the "middle" frame
    bottomFrame = 3          -- Number of the "bottom" frame
}
-- Table
local tableView = widget.newTableView(
    {
        left = -((panel.width)/2),
        top = -(((panel.height)/2) - menuIdBg.height - 8),
        height = panel.height-menuIdBg.height,
        width = panel.width,
        onRowRender = onRowRender,
        onRowTouch = onRowTouch,
        listener = scrollListener
    }
)
-- Insert rows
for i = 1, #menuRows do
    -- Insert a row into the tableView
    tableView:insertRow{
        rowHeight = 48,
        rowColor = { 1, 1, 1},
        lineColor = { 1, 1, 1},
        params=menuRows[i]
    }
end

panel:insert( tableView )


--everything below is to handle the left swipe touch to close the panel
--modified from https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/57554-detecting-separate-swipe-without-lifting-finger/
local lastX
local lastY 
local lastTime 
local swipeDirection = false
local lastDeltaX = 0
local lastDeltaY = 0

function panel:touch (event)

    if event.phase == "began" then
        lastX = event.x
        lastY = event.y
        lastTime = event.time
    elseif event.phase == "moved" then
        deltaX = event.x - lastX
        deltaY = event.y - lastY
        deltaTime = event.time - lastTime

        local xSpeed = deltaX / deltaTime
        local ySpeed = deltaY / deltaTime

        print(ySpeed)

        if swipeDirection == false then
            local xSpeedAbs = math.abs(xSpeed)
            local ySpeedAbs = math.abs(ySpeed)

            if xSpeedAbs > ySpeedAbs then
                if xSpeed > 0.8 then
                    swipeDirection = "right"
                    print ("right")
                elseif xSpeed < -0.8 then
                    swipeDirection = "left"
                    print ("left")
                    panel:hide()
                end
            end
        end
        lastX = event.x
        lastY = event.y
        lastTime = event.time
        lastDeltaX = deltaX
        lastDeltaY = deltaY

    elseif event.phase == "ended" or event.phase == "cancelled" then
        swipeDirection = false
        lastDeltaX = 0
        lastDeltaY = 0
    end
end -- screenTouched

panel:addEventListener("touch", panel)
```

I'd appreciate the help, Also is there a way to get the menu to follow the user finger direction? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging into `onRowTouch`, turns out there are ways to test for certain kind of touch events from within it. Long story short, I fixed my problem like this:

```
local function onRowTouch( event )
    local row = event.target
    local params=event.target.params

    print(event.phase)
    if event.phase == "tap" then
        panel:hide()
        composer.removeScene(composer.getSceneName("current"))
        composer.gotoScene( params.page)

    elseif event.phase == "swipeLeft" then
        panel:hide()
    end
end
```

This way, I can check for swipes and taps. I hadn't seen these phase before so I didn't know they existed. I'd still like some help getting the menu to follow the user's finger. Thanks!